# write image & json object to clipboard

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, electron, clipboard

I'm trying to write image and json object to window clipboard using clipboard API.
(I'm using vue and electron)
I succeeded to write image and plain text, but when I try to write json object it returns an error:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException   localhost/:1`

My code is (this.object is a JSON object)

```
const textBlob = new Blob(['this.object.data','this.object.data2',...], {type: 'text/plain'});
const objBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.object)], {type: 'application/json'});

// defined a canvas with an image

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  const item = new ClipboardItem({
    'image/png': blob,
    'text/plain': textBlob,
    'application/json': objBlob
  });
  navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-write'}).then((result) => {
    if (result.state === 'granted' || result.state === 'prompt') {
      navigator.clipboard.write([item]);
    }
  } 
}, 'image/png');
```

In this case,
it shows me the error, but if I remove `'application/json': objBlob` in the item then it works. Looks like the clipboard doesn't accept json object. It's strange.

However, I want to write an object to the clipboard along with an image.
Is there any solution to solve this problem? Maybe I should use the other thing than the clipboard API?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is [actively working on it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897289) but for the time being, they still don't support writing `"application/JSON"`...

So you still have to write it as `"text/plain"` (which should be enough for most apps).

```
const item = new ClipboardItem({
  'image/png': blob,
  'text/plain': objBlob
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a catch to see the actual error:
DOMException: Write type application/json not supported.

If you use plain/text or utf then you should be able to read the json back into an object.

I would only use the clipboard if the objects were being pasted into another app, otherwise I would use local or session storage.

```js
const objBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({'myobjLabel' : 'myObj'})], {type: 'text/plain'});

  const item = new ClipboardItem({
    'text/plain': objBlob
  });

  navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-write'}).then((result) => {
    if (result.state === 'granted' || result.state === 'prompt') {
      navigator.clipboard.write([item]).catch((ex) => { 
          console.log(ex) 
          } ); 
      }
    });
```